# Compile errors with boost::geometry::within

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to compile a program that uses boost::geometry::within but I am getting the following error:

> /usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/within.hpp: In instantiation of
>   ‘bool boost::geometry::within(const Geometry1&, const Geometry2&)
>   [with Geometry1 = legacy_point; Geometry2 =
>   std::vector]’: glcanvas.cpp:1460:57: required from here
>   /usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/within.hpp:295:55: error:
>   ‘apply’ is not a member of
>   ‘boost::geometry::dispatch::within, boost::geometry::point_tag,
>   boost::geometry::multi_point_tag>

My geometry is defined as follows:

```
struct legacy_point{
float x, y, z;
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D(legacy_point, float, cs::cartesian, x, y, z)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_MULTI_POINT(decltype(std::vector< legacy_point>{}))
```

And I am calling the following function:

```
boost::geometry::within(point, conv_layer);
```

where `point` is of `legacy_point` type and `conv_layer` is a vector of `legacy_point`. I can use the boost::geometry::distance function but getting the above error for within.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `boost::geometry::within` does not support checking whether a `multipoint` is within a `multipoint`.

See the table "Supported Geometries" on the help page, which has a big red X at the intersection of multipoint & multipoint on the table.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the first entry `point` is of type legacy_point which is not a multipoint, it is a single point.

Comment: Right, but that's not what the compiler thinks (look carefully at the compiler message which says that `Geometry1` and `Geometry2` are of type `std::vector<legacy_point>`. Are you calling `within` somewhere else?

Comment: You are right, there was a typo in the code. Still after correcting I get the same error.

    /usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/within.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool boost::geometry::within(const Geometry1&, const Geometry2&) [with Geometry1 = legacy_point; Geometry2 = std::vector<legacy_point>]’:
glcanvas.cpp:1460:57:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/within.hpp:295:55: error: ‘apply’ is not a member of ‘boost::geometry::dispatch::within<legacy_point, std::vector<legacy_point>, boost::geometry::point_tag, boost::geometry::multi_point_tag>’